# String split without removing the delimiters

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a query that will split my string but won't remove delimiters.

Input:

```
D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)
```

Output:

```
D
*
(
A
+
B
)
-
(
C
+
A
)
*
(
C
+
A
)
```

My delimiters:

```
+-/*)(
```

I tried :

```
select regexp_substr('D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)', '[^+]+', 1, level) from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)', '[^+]+', 1, level)is not null
```

But that removes delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have multi-character terms between the delimiters and can't just split on every character, you could wrap every delimiter in another single character - anything that can't appear in your original string, so possibly `^` (though you might use that to indicate an exponent) or as here `|`:

```
regexp_replace('D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)', '([+*/()-])', '|\1|')
```

which for your example gives:

```
D|*||(|A|+|B|)||-||(|C|+|A|)||*||(|C|+|A|)|
```

... and then split on that new character instead:

```
select regexp_substr(
  regexp_replace('D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)', '([+*/()-])', '|\1|'),
  '[^|]+', 1, level)
from dual
connect by regexp_substr(
  regexp_replace('D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)', '([+*/()-])', '|\1|'),
  '[^|]+', 1, level) is not null
```

```
D
*
(
A
+
B
)
-
(
C
+
A
)
*
(
C
+
A
)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c633f8d16eaaeff399e881052a871ec)

Normally this kind of simple split would be a slight concern as it misses null elements; but because the replace creates those where there are adjacent delimiters (so you get `|*||(|` etc.) that's OK here.

Possibly some edge cases it won't like though; such as a negative number.

Comment: Thank you, that's what it was about, there will only be letters in the pattern and earlier there is a validation of the correctness of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to get every character into its own row? If so, you don't need regular expressions, `substr` can handle that.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'D*(A+B)-(C+A)*(C+A)' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, level, 1) val
  4  from test
  5  connect by level <= length(col);

V
-
D
*
(
A
+
B
)
-
(
C
+
A
)
*
(
C
+
A
)

19 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It will not work in the case of DA*B-C, e.g. because it will split DA into D and A

Comment: Which means that your initial question was kind of misleading, as it didn't contain anything like that (and I can't read your mind).

Comment: I said about my delimiters.

Comment: Yes, but A and D (separated) aren't really AD. But never mind that, you got your answer, Alex reads minds way better than me.